# How to compare values foreach inside a foreach

Tags: c#

How would like to to compare values in this nested foreach.
    I want to compare and if they match print YES for example.
Cheers

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Use a string array to loop over.
        string[] ferns =
        {
            "apple",
            "Equisetopsida",
            "Marattiopsida",
            "Polypodiopsida"
        };

        string[] fruits=
        {
            "apple",
            "mango",
            "Marattiopsida",
            "Polypodiopsida"
        };
        // Loop with the foreach keyword.
        foreach (string value in ferns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);

            foreach (string value in fruits)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }

            //I would like to compare values here.
            //Compare frens values against fruits values.
            //How can i achieve this


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, in each of yours foreach, current element has this same name, and you will not be able to reach botch of them in second foreach.

To compare two string, you can use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) method. For example:

```
foreach (string fern in ferns)
{

    foreach (string fruit in fruits)
    {
        if(String.Compare(fern,fruit,false)==0)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("YES");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string fern in ferns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fern);

    foreach (string fruit in fruits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fruit);

        if(fruit.Equals(fern))
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to move the if (fruit.equals(fern)) inside the second foreach. fruit is only known inside the foreach.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(value);` won't write anything. I think you mean `fern` in the first one and `fruit` in the next.

Answer (score 1):

**Option A**

```
foreach (string fernsvalue in ferns)
{
    foreach (string fruitsvalue in fruits)
    {
       if (fernsvalue.Equals(fruitsvalue))
          Console.WriteLine("They are equal");
    }
}
```

**Option B**

```
List<string> fernsList = new List<string>(ferns.Length);
List<string> fruitsList = new List<string>(fruits.Length);
fernsList.AddRange(ferns);
fruitsList.AddRange(fruits);
List<string> Differences = fernsList.Except(fruitsList).ToList();
```

**Option C**

```
bool equal = ferns.SequenceEqual(fruits); //compares for exact equality
```

Comment: This should be correct. I tested the code an it didn't work as there are 2 identical variable defined (string value).

Comment: I cant see any value variable, are you refering to my answer or to the main post?

Comment: Off course to the main post :). Sorry forgot to mention it :)

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not a keyword here(through it is in some circumstances). All you have to do is pick  whatever variable name you like

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to compare them to see if they match in order? Or just if one list contains the other one at all?

If order counts, loop through both at same time with counter variable (just needs boundary checks):

```
        for (int x = 0; x < ferns.Length; x++)
        {
            if (ferns[x] == fruits[x])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES!");
            }
        }
```

If it just needs to contain it:

```
        foreach (string fern in ferns)
        {
            if (fruits.Contains(fern))
                Console.WriteLine("YES!");
        }
```

This would also be a good place to use an intersection. An intersection takes two lists and returns all the items that 'both' lists have in common.

```
       IEnumerable<string> commonWords = ferns.Intersect(fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to see if the elements in the arrays `fruits` and `ferns` match at the same index?  If so then a nested `foreach` loop isn't the best way to achieve this.  It's much easier to use a `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < ferns.Length && i < fruits.Length; i++) {
  if (fruits[i] == ferns[i]) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} YES!!!", fruits[i]);
  }
}
```

If instead you're looking to see if there is any match at all for an element in the `ferns` array in the `fruits` array then you could try the following

```
foreach (string fern in ferns) {
  Console.Write("{0} ", fern);
  bool isMatch = false;
  foreach (string fruit in fruits) {
    if (fruit == fern) { 
      isMatch = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(isMatch ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```